# Putting a line into the foreground inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am trying to create a bookshelf from an array of books I created and to strike a book through diagonally if the "recommended" property for the book is "false". You can see in my `for` loop that I try to do that with the following if statement:

```
if(books[i].recommended === false)
{
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    line(bookX,bookY,bookX+90,bookY+100);
}
```

However my problem is that the line I create in the `for` loop goes in the background, behind my books, and is thus invisible. How can I make it come to the foreground?

Full code below:

```
//I create my array with my books
var books = [];

for(var y = 1;y<=20;y++)
{
    books.push(
        {
            title: "Book "+y,
            stars: random(4),
            author: "Author "+y,
            color: color(random(255), random(255), random(255)),
            recommended: !!Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
        }
        );
}

// Loop to draw 3 shelves
var shelfY = 105;
while (shelfY<=360)
{
    fill(173, 117, 33);
    rect(0, shelfY, width, 10);
    shelfY +=120;
}

// Loop to draw all my books
var bookX = 5;
var bookY = 5;
for (var i = 0; i<books.length; i++)
{
    fill(books[i].color);
    rect(bookX, bookY, 90, 100);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(books[i].title, bookX+5, bookY+9, 70, 100);
    text(books[i].author, bookX+5, bookY+24, 70, 100);

    for (var j = 0; j < books[i].stars; j++) 
    {
        image(getImage("cute/Star"), bookX+3 + j * 20, bookY+70,20, 30);
    }

    bookX += 100;

    if(bookX>400)
    {
        bookX = 5;
        bookY += 120;
    }

    if(books[i].recommended === false)
    {
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        line(bookX,bookY,bookX+90,bookY+100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do the `fill` and `line` functions come from?

Comment: Whatever function is being called with `line` may need to be modified to accept a z-index argument, which will allow you to order the stack of the elements.

Comment: @skolsuper & @kaz this is [a problem I am trying to solve on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/objects/p/project-bookshelf) and the `fill` and `line` functions are default parts of their environment, hence I can't modify them myself. Any other way to solve my problem (i.e. showing my strikethrough lines on top of my books) without having to modify the `line` function?

Comment: I had a quick look on Khan Academy, apparently they use a port of Processing.js, I don't know much about it, sorry.  I added a tag to your post so someone who does is more likely to find it. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're drawing the line after increasing bookX and bookY, so it's not going to be drawn at the right place.

Try putting your if (books[i].recommended etc... before bookX += 100; and it will work.

That's the final code :

```js
//I create my array with my books
var books = [];

for(var y = 1;y<=20;y++)
{
    books.push(
        {
            title: "Book "+y,
            stars: random(4),
            author: "Author "+y,
            color: color(random(255), random(255), random(255)),
            recommended: !!Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
        }
        );
}

// Loop to draw 3 shelves
var shelfY = 105;
while (shelfY<=360)
{
    fill(173, 117, 33);
    rect(0, shelfY, width, 10);
    shelfY +=120;
}

// Loop to draw all my books
var bookX = 5;
var bookY = 5;
for (var i = 0; i<books.length; i++)
{
    fill(books[i].color);
    rect(bookX, bookY, 90, 100);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(books[i].title, bookX+5, bookY+9, 70, 100);
    text(books[i].author, bookX+5, bookY+24, 70, 100);

    for (var j = 0; j < books[i].stars; j++) 
    {
        image(getImage("cute/Star"), bookX+3 + j * 20, bookY+70,20, 30);
    }

    if(books[i].recommended === false)
    {
        fill(0, 0, 0);
        line(bookX,bookY,bookX+90,bookY+100);
    }

    bookX += 100;

    if(bookX>400)
    {
        bookX = 5;
        bookY += 120;
    }

}
```

Comment: So sorry for the delay. I just accepted the answer! Thanks again!